# How do I Stop WPF DataContext Failure After Changing an Object Reference?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

Using MVVM, my viewmodel is my WPF window's data context. In the viewmodel is an observablecollection that holds the items in a listbox. When I add items to the collection, the listbox updates as expected

As part of my generic undo function, the observablecollection can be replaced with an older version. This happens by passing the collection to a method by reference and changing the reference. Everything after the undo works correctly except for the listbox. This continues to show data from the old reference.

How can I either stop this from happening or change the reference that the datacontext uses so that my listbox is "undone" and then continues working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some change notification in order to trigger the UI to update which you won't get from reassigning a ref variable to another instance. To get the notification you can either Clear and re-fill the original ObservableCollection instance or fire a PropertyChanged event for the collection property's name after swapping the instances.

Comment: The problem is not that there is no change notified. When I add further items to the collection they stop appearing because the listbox remembers the old reference.

Comment: ...if I reset the ItemsSource manually in the window's code-behind it all still works. But this is not very good for MVVM!

Comment: @Jimbob - It will be better to raise PropertyChanged in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Jimbob - The ListBox is using the old collection because you haven't notified it to update its ItemsSource Binding which is why you need the PropertyChanged notification if you're going to change the instance returned by the bound property. If you directly assign the ItemsSource property you're replacing the binding so there's no notification needed but as you said, that defeats the purpose of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVVM pattern, properties are changed in the ViewModel, with setters raising the PropertyChanged event.  The event is handled in the View (automatically by WPF) and bindings are refreshed.

In your case, the value is being changed without the setter being called, so the PropertyChanged event (if it exists) is not being raised.

One option might be to manually raise the PropertyChanged event from the `undo` code.  This would allow you to keep your existing design (please note that `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` is different to `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` - do a bit of research if this is not clear).

The second option would be to handle the CollectionChanged event, and keep a record of ItemsAdded and ItemsRemoved.
Your undo mechanism can then re-add any items which were removed, or remove any items which were added.  This might require a bit of design tweaking.

I would go with the second design, as I think the design rethink might be a good idea.  If you are using MVVM, you should be using Commands, and if you are using Commands you can implement Undo/Redo functionality neatly by extending the Commands (remember that an action made by a user is usually a bit more than a value change).